# Find the sum of digits in the product of $A$ and $B$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

My question is

If $A$= $9999...........$($77$ times or $77$ digits) and

$B$= $7777............$($99$ times or $99$ digits)
Then find the sum of digits in the product of $A$ and $B$.
I have a query that if we have same number of digits then i can easily figure out the sum but in the question it is different. Any help will be appreciated.

Note: $$9.7 = 63$$
      $$99.77=7623$$
      $$999.777=776223$$ and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A=999...(77$ times)= $10^{78}-1$

$B=777...(99$ times)= $10^{98}.7+10^{97}.7+.....+10^{77}+10^{76}.7+10^{75}.7+....+7$

so.

$AB=10^{78}.B-B$

$= 77..(78$times)$6$$22...(97$times)3

$\implies$ sum of the digits= $78 \times 7 + 6 + 97 \times 2 +3  $

there can be some mistake in the calculation. but i think we can do it this way

Comment: i think the answer should be 
$76 \times 7 +22 \times 9+ 6 +76 \times 2 +3=891$

Comment: $$\quad \underbrace {77....777}_{76digits}\;6\quad \underbrace {99....999}_{22{\kern 1pt} digits}\;\underbrace {22....222}_{76{\kern 1pt} digits}3

$$

Answer (score 0):

we have $A=999...9$ which has $77$ digits and  $B=777..7$ which has $99$ digits.

Now Let $X=777..7$ which has $77$ digits and $Y=777..7000...0$ which has $22$ sevens and $77$ Zeros. So

$$B=777..7+777..7000...0=X+Y$$ Also $Y=Z*10^{77}$ where $Z=777..77$ with $22$ Sevens.

$$AB=A(X+Y)$$

According to your Note $$AX=777..76222...23$$ which has $76$ Sevens and $76$ Twos.So Total digits of number $AX$ is $154$.

Similarly $$AY=0000..0777..7000..0$$ which has $55$ Zeros in front, $22$ Sevens and $77$ Zeros at last with total digits as again $154$. Now simply add $AX$ and $AY$ by aligning $154$ digits of $AX$ with corresponding $154$ digits of $AY$ you will get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In light  of@user300 answer

The resultant number will be 
$ \quad \underbrace {77....777}_{76digits}\;6\quad \underbrace {99....999}_{22{\kern 1pt} digits}\;\underbrace {22....222}_{76{\kern 1pt} digits}3$

So the sum =$76 \times 7 +22 \times 9+76 \times 2 +6+3=891$